# Why do you need to pass in this.state.example for page to rerender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this inside my render:

```
{this.availProps(this.state.data)}
```

`this.state.data` is updated with a fetch when componentOnMount

```
availProps = data =>{
    if (data.length == 0) 
        return (
            <option>"hello"</option>
        )
    else 
    return (    
        <option> "hi" </option>
        )
}
```

It prints out "hi" just fine when the data is done fetching.
However, if I use:

```
{this.availProps()}
```

and

```
   availProps = () =>{
        if (this.state.data.length == 0) 
            return (
                <option>"hello"</option>
            )
        else 
        return (    
            <option> "hi" </option>
            )
    }
```

It will not work. It prints out "hello" instead.

Is this because the page is only rerendered if a variable inside the "render" is changed/updated? ( in this case, this.state.data)

Thank you

edit: here is the componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb()
}


getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/property")
      .then(property => property.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }))
      .then(() =>{
          for(var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
              if (this.state.data[i].status == 0)
                  this.state.useData.push(this.state.data[i])
          }
      }).then
    ( ()=> console.log(this.state.useData))
};
```

Comment: Can you also paste the `componentDidMount` code ? You don't have to pass in the state object from `render`.

Comment: I have posted the componentDidMount. After it does the this.setState in getDataFromDB, it doesn't seem to rerender the page when the updated info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the property directly on `this.state` does not invoke the render method.

You will have to use `this.setState({ useData: useData })` so that react will that something has changed which runs the render method.

And since the state that is being set is based on the previous state, it is better you use state updater pattern and its callback so that the updated state is available when you try to access it.

[Do not update state directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

```js
getDataFromDb = () => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/property")
    .then(property => property.json())
    .then(res => this.setState({
      data: res.data
    }))
    .then(() => {
      // Your computations are based on previous state
      // use the updater function to have access to the latest
      // state as state updates are asynchronous
      this.setState((previousState) => {
        const {
          data
        } = previousState;

        // accessing this.state here might have stale data

        const updatedUseData = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
          if (obj.status === 0) {
            acc.push(obj);
          }

          return acc;
        }, []);

        // this will invoke the render again as 
        // a state is updated
        return {
          useData: updatedUseData
        }
      }, () => {
        // Use the call back which gets invoked once the state
        // is updated
        console.log(this.state.useData)
      })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A component will rerender by default if a value from `props` or `state` is changed, which is being used in the render or in a function that the render is calling.

If you had a class-level variable, such as `this.example` and were using that in the render, changing that value wouldn't make the component rerender.

You can also override `shouldComponentUpdate` to prevent the component from re-rendering when certain values of `props` or `state` changes, if you wish to do that. You can read more about that [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate). As it says, it's not recommended to do this, unless you're confident that you're handling it correctly.

---

**EDIT**

As the other answer suggests, only values updated using `this.setState` will cause a re-render. Doing something like:

```
this.state.useData.push(this.state.data[i])
```

will not cause it to update. I'd suggest the following change to `getDataFromDb` to handle this

```
getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/property")
        .then(property => property.json())
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data, useData: res.data.filter(item => item.status === 0) });
        }).then
            ( ()=> console.log(this.state.useData))
};
```

Just as an aside, `setState` is async so `console.log` on the `.then` won't necessarily see this change yet.